# Cordova PushPlugin Error: TypeError: Result of expression 'cordova.exec' [undefined] is not a function

Tags: android, cordova

I am currently using Cordova 3.1.0.
I installed the following standard plugins which works fine:

- org.apache.cordova.device
- org.apache.cordova.network-information

I am trying to get the [PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin) working.
I did the manual install as specified.

When I run the app on an emulator or device, I get the following error:

**TypeError: Result of expression 'cordova.exec' [undefined] is not a function.**

Anyone have any ideas.

Comment: Did you solve this issue?